# Standard ML and lookup tables with a find function

Tags: lookup, sml, ml

Creating a Lookup function using a fold function SML

I need to create a function in Standard ML called lookup(k, table) that returns NONE if k is not a key in the lookup table and returns (SOME (k,v)) if (k,v) is in the table. For example lookup(3, [(1,4),(14,5),(7,3),(22,6]) is NONE and lookup (1,[(1,4),(14,5),(7,3,(22,6)]) is (SOME (1,4)).

And i want to use this find function:

```
fun find pred [] = NONE
  | find pred (x::rest) = if pred x then SOME x else find pred rest;
```

This is what i have so far:

```
fun lookup(k,table) = NONE
 | lookup(k, find(k,table)) =
    if k = SOME then SOME else NONE;
```

Please help me, I have been pulling out hair because of this ML problem.

Comment: So what isn't working for you?  I'd note to start with that your syntax is a bit off.  Including `find(k,table)` makes it looks like you're trying to pattern match.  Also, the function `find` is curried, and you're trying to use it in a tupled form.  Perhaps you can distill down some specific questions and post specific error messages if you're getting them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have confused pattern matching with function application here. In a function definition, you can do pattern matching, i.e. define cases that apply iff the arguments of the actual call of the function match the patterns (comprised of constructors and variables) given for the parameters. What you cannot do is calling a function on the left-hand side of the function definition's equal sign: The use of *find* in `... | lookup(k, find(k, table))` is invalid.

This code will return the first key-value pair in *table* whose key matches *k*:

```
fun lookup(k,table) = 
  find (fn (key, value) => key = k) table
```

It uses the function *find* to go through the table; *find* will use the abstraction `fn (key, value) => key = k` to decompose each key-value pair in *table* and check if the key matches *k*. *lookup* will return *find*'s result, which will either be `SOME x`, if *(k, x)* is in *table*, or `NONE`, if not.